# How to trigger a reminder mail for an event using Plone 4.1

Tags: python, plone

I would like  to trigger a mail as reminder for an event, 2 days before the actual event occurs. How do I achieve this. Is there any sample code for the same which I could access.I am using Plone 4.1 with default zope. In short it should be a time based event.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't tried this yet but I believe this plugin should do what you want http://plone.org/products/collective.topicitemsevent

Comment: I ma able to use the buildout for the add-on.Also added the cron4plone. Exactly what I want, but I don't find the 'Topic' in any add new dropdown menu option. How to go about?

Comment: Topics are now called Collections

Comment: I have follwed the instructions in the url mentioned, using collections,all steps 1-3 done and tested. In step 4, I gave the cron job as 48 11 * * 18.229.127.11:8084/Plone/events/event_collection/@@fire-topicitems-events, but nothing happened, didn't get the test mail. Anything wrong in the cron syntax, The cron tab in ZMI shows the entry, but I couldn't get the mail as per the content rule set on it

Comment: try the command from your cron config by itself on the command line to check it works. It looks like you are missing something